# MVC model with a property for related models

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Imagine there is a model defined as:

```
public class Book
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> RelatedBooks { get; set; } // List<Book> would be more ideal.
}
```

I'm trying to add a field in both the Create and Edit views whereby a user will be able to search for related items, in this example by name, and then add them to the new/current item as a related item.

I think this might be possible with a partial view + jQuery, where the partial view acts a search box and returns a list of items. Then with some buttons and jQuery magic these could be added to the current model upon submission of the parent form.

I'm not against using jQuery if it's the only option, but I was wondering if there were any alternatives?

If this is too vague I'm happy to add some more specific details, I've tried search for similar questions but I'm either using the wrong search terms or there aren't any.

Any help would be really appreciated - I'd rather not go down the jQuery + partial view route if there is a cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to create a view-model for what you're trying to achieve that will hold both the list of related books, but also a list of all books we can select.

```
public class CreateBookViewModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> RelatedBooks { get; set; }

    public List<Book> AllBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Populate AllBooks in the Controller and return the view model. Then you could create some magic, maybe with jQuery, to have a select list with all books, that when selected are added to the list of related books by Id. At least you wouldn't need partial views, if you don't want any more functionality than just selecting one or more books.

Comment: Ah yeah, the model in question was hypothetical (I do use view models in my actual implementation) - I have considered the above, but it prevents the user from being able to search through all of the books, and also means loading every single book every time they may want to create or edit one which eventually (with _lots_ of books) will not be good for performance. 
Thanks for the input though, really appreciate it, and if I can't find an alternative, a proof of concept like the above will be a good starting point.

Comment: @Callum Will edit my answer when I have time then, because then I definitely think you should use jQuery (or any other Javascript framework for that matter) to have an autocomplete searchbox on the create/edit page, which requests book from an AJAX endpoint on some controller based on the search condition.